# mongodb - compound unique index using spring data not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, unique-index, compound-index

I am trying to create unique compound index in mongodb using spring data.
But I see that the index is **not** created and the **duplicate document** is created in the DB.

My entity class:

```
@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@CompoundIndexes(
        @CompoundIndex(name = "daybook_index", def = "{'date' : 1, 'vehicleNumber' : 1}", unique = true)
)
public class Daybook {

    private String date;
    private String vehicleNumber;
    private String unit;
}
```

I am using `repository.insert()` method to create the document.

When I see in mongo express I see only one index created on `_id` and the index defined in the entity class is not created.

[image]

Is it a bug in spring data or am I doing something wrong?

P.S.: I tried to delete the collection too before running the application but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Saxon mentioned:

> Spring Data MongoDB 3.0, automatic index creation is turned off by default.

Instead of adding code, I am able to create the index by adding the spring data configuration in `application.properties`

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Data MongoDB 3.0, automatic index creation is turned off by default.
To turn it on you might use the proper flag overriding the method from MongoConfigurationSupport:

```
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    .....
    @Override
    protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

otherwise you might create the index with appropriate instructions.

```
mongoOperations.indexOps(Daybook.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("date", Direction.ASC).on("vehicleNumber", Direction.ASC).unique());
```